# Is it correct to say "I am jumping up and down on the bottom of the pool" or "I am jumping up and down from the bottom of the pool"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You are standing in a rather shallow pool (about 1 meter in height), then you start to jump up and down.

Does water medium affect the way we express ideas?

Is it correct to say "**I am jumping up and down on the bottom of the pool**" or "**I am jumping up and down from the bottom of the pool**"?

Answer (score 3):

From your description, people might conclude that the pool was empty.

To be clear that there's water in the pool, you need to say:

> I am jumping up and down in the (waist-deep) water in the pool.

The water would obviously be in the bottom of the pool.

It is not idiomatic to say that you are jumping up and down **from** the bottom of the pool.